# PrimeNG: In p-table horizotal bar comes between body and footer in unfrozen view

Tags: angular, primeng

```css
.ui-table .ui-table-frozen-view .ui-table-tbody > tr > td,
.ui-table .ui-table-unfrozen-view .ui-table-tbody > tr > td {
    height: 24px !important;
}
```

```html
<h3>Frozen Column Groups</h3>
<div style="width:800px">
    <p-table [value]="sales" [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="200%" frozenWidth="200px" >
        <ng-template pTemplate="frozencolgroup">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:200px;">
            </colgroup>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="colgroup">
            <colgroup>
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
                <col style="width:80px;">
            </colgroup>
            </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="frozenheader">
            <tr>
                <th style="height:84px">Brand</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="frozenbody" let-sale>
            <tr>
                <td>{{sale.brand}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="frozenfooter" let-sale>
            <tr>
                <td>One</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="8">Sale Rate</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Sales</th>
                <th colspan="2">Profits</th>
                <th colspan="1">A</th>
                <th colspan="1">B</th>
                <th colspan="1">C</th>
                <th colspan="1">Profits</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Last </th>
                <th>This </th>
                <th>Last </th>
                <th>This </th>
                <th colspan="1">A</th>
                <th colspan="1">B</th>
                <th colspan="1">C</th>
                <th colspan="1">Profits</th>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-sale>
            <tr>
                <td>{{sale.lastYearSale}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.thisYearSale}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.lastYearProfit}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.thisYearProfit}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.lastYearSale}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.thisYearSale}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.lastYearProfit}}</td>
                <td>{{sale.thisYearProfit}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template pTemplate="footer" let-sale>
                <tr>
                    <td>One</td>
                </tr>
        </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

I am using `primeng 6.0.0-beta.1.` I have created a p-table with a frozen and unfrozen view. I have added frozenfooter and plain 'footer'. The issue is the horizontal bar comes between body and footer in unfrozen view. Can someone tell me how to make the horizontal bar come after the footer?

I have added frozenheader, frozenbody, frozenfooter and plain header, body, footer

Image
[image]

Comment: it will be great if you add your some HTML code here.

Comment: I have added the html code.

Comment: Event Now I am facing same issue, if you solve the issue can you post the answer

Comment: Hey did you get any solution for above issu,?